need to map x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields: true to a variable in go operator
I have a requirement so that my crd accept dynamic structure with some predefined structure for a particular parameter like PmScrape.
So, I have defined below in types.go of go operator
type PmScrape struct {
Enable          bool                 json:"enable,omitempty" yaml:"enable"
Port            int32                json:"port,omitempty" yaml:"port"
AddData         runtime.RawExtension json:",inline" yaml:",inline"
}
so that additional data can be passed. Below section of CRD generated which is good as it is expecting unknown-fields and it is preserving them as well.
          pmScrape:
            description: PM Scrape Settings
            properties:
              enable:
                type: boolean
              port:
                format: int32
                type: integer
            type: object
            x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields: true

Now I passed below section in CR Spec.
pmScrape:
f: 1
enable: true
port: 9250
As per my understanding by using inline, f: 1 will be saved to AddData and I can use it in go code. But When I am trying to print Cr.Spec.PmScrape at the start of reconcile, it is printing as
{true 9250 {[] }}
AddData is null and i cant find f: 1.
How can I handle this?
